# css ".selected" in angular.js ng-repeat does not work properly

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I have simple radio buttons. I have a `.selected` class that turns the "+10", "0" and "X" labels red if you select one of them. This works:

http://jsfiddle.net/KRMRU/18/

However, if all of the above reside inside an angular.js- table, this does not work

http://jsfiddle.net/KRMRU/17/

I assume that the jQuery `$(this).addClass` does not work properly and I'd need something else... Any ideas?

Comment: Because the table is rendered dynamically, your jQuery code will run "too soon" (when the table hasn't rendered yet) and the elements you try to attach event handlers (and add classes) to won't exist in the DOM yet. The best way to solve this is not to use jQuery at all, but something like [ngClass](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why your click isn't working but I found a workaround:

if you use the following jQuery below your main function it should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sites input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
    $(document).on('click', '#sites label', function() {
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/KRMRU/25/

Comment: yeah but in jQuery it's a nice one-liner! Angular probably means ng-click=something() and then ...more code

Comment: @graph well obviously, but there must be a good reason why you're using Angular, right? The suggested code works for this specific example, but when your Angular app gets only a bit more complicated it'll stop working again.

Comment: Yes of course. I just threw that out there to bait a "well here is the equivalent one-liner in pure angular.js". At the bottom of this page http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass there is a nice example, but cleaning up all the siblings()... meh

Comment: @graph well you wouldn't catch me using Angular 0.10.5 ;) anyway, have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Another option that does not rely on jQuery

(getting in the habit of using jQuery in AngularJs can result in pain if not used correctly)

How about just some simple css:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked+label{ background-color: red; }
```

If the radio is checked the next label will be marked with a red background.

***(btw, why are you using Angular 0.10.5?)***

Comment: I'm old school. Wait, I'm not. I used someone else's existing angular jsfiddle to reproduce a minimal version of my problem. I like your solution, but since there's a radio button element in each (dynamically generated) line I think I need a reference to which line I'm in when I click.